# Bootstrap: How to align a paragraph next to the center of an img?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I'm relatively new to Bootstrap and HTML/CSS. I want to align a paragraph to the center of an image on the same row. The image has to be on the left (e.g., `pull-left` class).

This is what I have written:

```
  <div class="container">  
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span12">
        <h2>Leeuwkes</h2>
        <img class="pull-left" alt="" src="img/groepen/leeuwkesEmbleem.jpg" height="200" width="200"/>
        <p>
          De Leeuwkes zijn onze jongste kapoenen onder ons. Zit jij in het eerste of tweede leerjaar, 
          trek dan je laarzen aan en kom elke zondag van 14u tot 16u30 met ons mee ravotten! 
          Ben jij een echte modderfan of hang je liever het aapje uit, heb je veel fantasie of hou je van
          spelen, SPELEN, SPELEN, kom dan zeker een kijkje nemen! We verwachten jullie met open armen.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It looks like this image:

[image]

I want it to look like this image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you have to give top and bottom padding of the paragraph
like:

```
p{
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

or you can create a class for this paragraph and add this styling to the class

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML is flexible you can change it to this:

```css
img, span {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.span12 {
  display:table;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Leeuwkes</h2>
    <div class="span12">
      <img alt="" src="http://www.placekitten.com/200/200" height="200" width="200" />
      <span>De Leeuwkes zijn onze jongste kapoenen onder ons. Zit jij in het eerste of tweede leerjaar, 
          trek dan je laarzen aan en kom elke zondag van 14u tot 16u30 met ons mee ravotten! 
          Ben jij een echte modderfan of hang je liever het aapje uit, heb je veel fantasie of hou je van
            spelen, SPELEN, SPELEN, kom dan zeker een kijkje nemen! We verwachten jullie met open armen.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use flex property for this purpose.

```
 .box{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  }
```

here is the fiddle for understanding https://jsfiddle.net/arkqjq47/

Comment: Ok this centers the paragraph next to the image. Now when the screen gets smaller, the image doesn't resize (to a smaller size). And the text just lines up to a minimum of one word per line.

Comment: just wrap it in a div and give this div 50% width .. and 100% width to image .. http://jmp.sh/fu3hIOh